# Choosing on which screen my win8 app starts when debugging

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, multiscreen

Simple situation: I have two monitors and I would like my win8 app to launch on screen 2 while I still have VS2012 in debug mode on screen 1. This way there is no context switch necessary on a breakpoint and I find it far more confortable.

The other day, I had this behavior and thought it was great. But after a reboot I'm back to the old behavior: my app starts on the same screen as VS2012 and screen 2 is of no use.

Does anybody know how to control on which screen the win8 app starts, and how to control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multi-monitor setup, only one screen at a time can be used for the "Modern Style" UI.  The default screen used can be changed by dragging a Windows Store app (or the start screen) to the other monitor.  To drag the app to another monitor, move the mouse to the top of the screen and start dragging (as if you were going to close or snap the app) and drag it to the other screen.

Another option is to bring up the start screen on the other monitor (move your mouse to the bottom-left corner of the target screen and click to open the start screen).

You will find that (for the current session at least) your app will now start on the screen you wish it to.